# Unable to share data between unrelated components from a service using Behavior Subject in Angular

Tags: angular, service, behaviorsubject

I am new to Angular. I have a cart service and two un-related components - ProductList Component and Nav Component. I am subscribing to the service in both the components, updating the cart count in ProductList Component but the Nav Component is still showing the initial count instead of updated one. Can any one please help.

```
@Injectable()
export class CartService {

  private initialCount = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  currentCount = this.initialCount.asObservable();
  //cartCount : BehaviorSubject<number>= new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  changeCount(count: number) : number {
    this.initialCount.next(count);
    console.log("count in cart service ::: "+count);
    return count;
  }

}
```

ProductList Component :

```
export class ProductListComponent{

    count : number;

    constructor(private _cartService : CartService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this._cartService.currentCount.subscribe(count => this.count = count);
    }
    newCount() : number{
        return this._cartService.changeCount(this.count + 1)
    }
}
```

ProductList Component HTML:

```
<button (click)='newCount()'><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart">{{count}}</i></button>
```

Nav Component :

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  count : number;

  constructor(private _cartService : CartService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this._cartService.currentCount.subscribe(count => this.count = count);
    console.log('count in Nav Component :: '+this.count);
  }

}
```

NavComponent HTML :

```
<a class="nav-link">Cart ( <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"> {{count}} </i> )</a>
```

The count in NavComponent HTML is always showing 0. Please help

Comment: My guess is that you provided the service in each component rather than providing it in the root NgModule. So each component has its own instance of the service.

Comment: also in cart service why are your doing this _return count;_

Comment: @JBNizet I have provided the service in root NGModule only

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as a StackBlitz.

Comment: @RahulSingh I have modified my code now to remove return in cartservice and productList Componet newCount() method

Comment: does it work , you just need to call that from the component and then the other component will be notified of the change

Comment: @JBNizet Here is the StackBlitz. https://angular-rqozhm.stackblitz.io/products and https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqozhm?file=app%2Fnav%2Fnav.component.ts. Some css is missing, please ignore the styles. In the products page, there is a list of products and each product has an "Add to Cart" button. When clicked on the button, the count is getting updated where as remains zero in the navigation link 0 Cart

Comment: @RahulSingh Please see my comment above

Comment: @JBNizet I have installed missing dependencies to fix the styling. Hope it would be helpful for you to debug now

Comment: Just rename currentCount with currentCount$ and try it will work. $ suffix (popularized by Cycle.js) is used to indicate that the variable is an Observable.

Comment: Inject CartService in your AppModule as providers and do not inject it anywahere else, it will work

Comment: @Akanksha Yes that worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are re-providing the CartService in ProductListComponent... hence getting a different instance than the global one. 
Just remove it from the providers in ProductListComponent and it works.

BTW : you can check the docs for the injector tree, and as you are working with observables, you should also check the ChangeDetection strategies (OnPush would be better in your case).
Also using something like :

````
// in nav.component.ts
count$: Observable<number>
...

this.count$ = this._cartService.currentCount
...

// in nav.component.html
...
{{count$ | async}}
...

```
````

would be more idiomatic and handle unsubscribing and change detection for you.

Comment: Thank you all :) Removing cart service as a provider in each individual component made it work.

Comment: Sure, thanks for sharing that info. It indeed helped

Comment: Am re-opening this question with a different issue. I am having an array of product ids and wanted to send http get requests based on the id from the array which is looped. Can you please help.

Please see the error in the cart page by adding products in this page - angular-rqozhm.stackblitz.io/products The code is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqozhm?file=app%2Fcart%2Fcart.service.ts and https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqozhm?file=app%2Fcart%2Fcart.component.ts